# Why flair is not loading In the Edit Profile & Setting section?

Tags: support, bug, combined-flair

Here you can see this flair is not loading:

Location: [Edit Profile & Setting](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current)

What is the problem?

[image]

Comment: Where do you see this exactly? Please post a link or at least describe the location, it's not trivial.

Comment: Looks like it's from the flair tab of network profile, but for me the wording is different, so no idea what's going on, maybe you have some userscript messing things up or something like that.

Comment: On seeing the font in the screenshot, it is from SO - Edit Profile - Flair page.

Comment: @Sha The wording is exact same, look at the network flair.

Comment: Your flair resides at https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/4112140.png and loads correctly for me.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, flair location my in network profile page

Comment: Let me check it now.

Comment: Now It's working correctly

Comment: I've found the same problem. I didn't investigate it until a bug report, but I suspect it may have something with the https to do. Could you try to insert it with https?

Comment: Let me try I update you in a bit @peterh

Comment: Right now it's working fine for me @peterh